# Understanding algebraic closure of finite fields

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field) I learn that finite fields are not closed: If $F$ has $a_1,\dots,a_n$ then one could construct a polynomial $f(x) = (x-a_1)\cdot \ldots \cdot (x-a_n) + 1$ which has no roots (no zeros in $F$).

However, we don't need to go that far in creating the polynomial that uses every root, shouldn't $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ show that it has no roots? Am I right or am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: For instance, $x^2+1$ has $x=1$ as a root in $\mathbb F_2$.

Comment: This community is a fantastic community! 12 seconds after posting my question, Dave, wow! I guess x^2+1 has no root in $F_3$ (guessing), but the equation of the formula will give no zero solutions for $F_3$ ?

Comment: Yes it is true that $x^2+1$ has no roots in $\mathbb F_3$, but my last comment suggests that $x^2+1$ sometimes has roots in finite fields. The original polynomial certainly has no roots over any finite field since it evaluates to $1\neq 0$ at every point in the finite field.

Comment: In fact, $x^2+1$ has a root in $\mathbb F_p$ for each prime $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.

Comment: mind explaining how you calculated it?

Comment: It's just a known result in number theory that $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ for every prime $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$.

Comment: $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_{q^n}$ is the algebraic closure of $F_q$

Comment: A general (still relatively easy) fact is the following. *Every polynomial $f(x)\in\Bbb{F}_q[x]$ has all its zeros in some finite field $\Bbb{F}_Q$, $Q=q^m$. But there is no finite field $\Bbb{F}_Q$ such that all the polynomials in $\Bbb{F}_q[x]$ would have a zero in $\Bbb{F}_Q$.* I think digesting that statement will give you a more coherent picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both you and Wikipedia are right. Let me elaborate. Wikipedia tries to give a proof that *economizes on assumptions*. That is, the polynomial they construct is by a uniform procedure and works for all finite fields and the proof is just one line.

In contrast in your method you are trying to *economize on the degree of the polynomial*. So you want to give  a polynomial that does not have a root, degree being 2 irrespective of the field, while Wikipedia polynomial has degree as big as the cardinality of the finite field.

Existence of a solution to the equation $x^2+1=0$ is equivalent to finding an element of order $4$ in the multiplicative group of the field. So using Lagrange theorem we can show this polynomial works when the order of the field is NOT 1 modulo 4.  For fields where this hypothesis is not valid you need to produce a different polynomial.

Remember Euclid's proof of the infinitude of prime numbers: the prime that is shown to exist is not necessarily the immediate next. (If $2,3,5$ are the only prime numbers we know then $2\times3\times5 +1= 31$ is not first prime after $5$).